# spacy python package no longer runs

Tags: python, spacy

Running python 3.11.3 on macos, Intel.

I had spacy working fine. I then decided to try adding gpu support with: `pip install -U 'spacy[cuda113]'` but started getting errors.

I uninstalled with `pip uninstall 'spacy[cuda113]'` and then reinstalled spacy with just `pip install spacy`.

However, I'm still getting the same errors when running a simple script with just

`import spacy` in it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/steve/workshop/python/blah.py", line 4, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/attributeruler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .pipe import Pipe
  File "spacy/pipeline/pipe.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipe
  File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.vocab
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/tokens/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .doc import Doc
  File "spacy/tokens/doc.pyx", line 36, in init spacy.tokens.doc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/schemas.py", line 158, in <module>
    class TokenPatternString(BaseModel):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 369, in __new__
    cls.__signature__ = ClassAttribute('__signature__', generate_model_signature(cls.__init__, fields, config))
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/utils.py", line 231, in generate_model_signature
    merged_params[param_name] = Parameter(
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 2722, in __init__
    raise ValueError('{!r} is not a valid parameter name'.format(name))
ValueError: 'in' is not a valid parameter name
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure how/why these commands fixed the issue, but they did:

```
pip uninstall spacy
pip uninstall spacy_legacy
pip uninstall spacy_alignments
pip uninstall spacy_loggers
pip uninstall pydantic
pip install 'pydantic<1.8'
pip install spacy
pip uninstall pydantic
pip install pydantic
pip install spacy-alignments
pip install spacy-transformers
pip uninstall spacy
pip install spacy
```

Comment: For me, it's `pip uninstall pydantic && pip install pydantic` The older version of pydantic breaks on newer Python https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/5048 but it's fixed in pydantic 1.10

Comment: worked for me as well, running python 3.11 and spacy 3.6.1

Comment: I was having same issue.   I followed the install/unistall steps by StevieD and it worked.   Many Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled pydantic then installed it again.I got it fixed in pydantic 1.10.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34635029)